# ¿Cómo validar por fecha y hora futura en django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Mi *view* me devuelve un diccionario con dos campos fecha `2015-04-23` hora `17:34:31` y en mi *template* tengo que validar que si la fecha es futura me muestre un botón, o sino un mensaje inválido.

Tengo lo siguiente para la fecha y hora:

```
{% if val.date < now "Y-m-d" and val.hour < now "H:m:s" %}
```

¿Qué tengo mal o qué debo hacer?

Comment: Amigo y porque no lo haces con JavaScript ? O deseas que sea desde django ?

Comment: No manejo muy bien JavaScript  ¿me prodrías ayudar con una forma?

Comment: El diccionario devuelve la fecha y hora como datetimes? si es ese el caso simplemente debes comparar  valores, por ejemplo: `{% if val.date < now and val.date.time < now.time %}`